# JSF Integration with other JSF application

Tags: jsf-2

Currently we have 3 .war files built using JSF1.x I am going to create one more .war file using JSF 2.x There are some requirements to integrate with other .war files. All these war files are deployed separately meaning not in a .ear file.

Some of the integration scenarios are:

1. Existing .war1 will call the new application by clicking a link. The new application should prepopulate (Edit mode) its page and after submitting and processing the business logic it should show .war1 page
2. Existing .war2 will call the new application by clicking a link. The new application should just open a page (New mode). After submitting and processing the business logic it should take back to .war2 page
3. New application will call .war3 page by clicking a button. It will also send some data and after submitting from .war3 page, control should come back to the new application page. In this scenario there are more possiblities to exchange large amount of data.

Basically I am looking for the best way to integrate and pass bulk data between JSF 1.x and JSF 2.X application

Answer (score 0):

If cookies can be used to pass the data that is the easiest approach. Otherwise, you can have a server side cache such as EHCache and send a cacheId with the inter-app requests to point to where the data is cached.

Comment: All the applications are deployed in different server so caching is not an option and cookies is also not an option. How to invoke the other JSF application passing bulk data from the JSF link and button, I would like to see some code.

Comment: Actually distributed cache is perfect for multiple server deployment, see: http://ehcache.org/documentation/distributed_caching_with_terracotta.html for code and examples.

Comment: I know cache can be distributed but caching is not the solution for my problem. I think you got my question wrong. On clicking a link or button I want to view a jsf page that is deployed in other war file.